# Why Does WPF Swallow Databinding Exceptions?

Tags: wpf, exception, data-binding

I am in the process of learning WPF, and am puzzled by the fact that databinding exceptions do not cause a runtime/unhandled exception.

Can anyone explain the benefits of databinding working in this way?  I'm assuming that there **are** benefits, but so far I don't see any (disclaimer: I am just getting started with databinding).

Links to resources that explain the theoretical (or practical) reasons for making this decision would work as well.

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/978887/why-does-wpf-databinding-swallow-exceptions

Comment: Not a dupe.  This question is about why, linked question is about what to do about it.

Comment: The first answer in the linked question explains what to do about it. Custom trace source ftw.

Comment: Kent: I think you misread Phil's comment.  This question is about *why*, **NOT** "what do do about it."  The answers to the other question do *not* answer Phil's question.

Comment: Kent: please re-read my question and the linked question.  Not remotely a duplicate.  I am not asking what to do about it, I'm asking WHY it works that way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know for sure, but I suspect it's because there's nowhere to handle the exception.

Suppose you have something whose properties you want to bind to, but sometimes that something is null.  (For example, `{Binding Name.Length}`, where Name is a string property that might be null.)  In this case you're happy for this to be a no-op, because you know the control will never be shown when the Name is null (due to a trigger say) or because you know this will be a transient condition while the binding source is loading its data.

Now suppose WPF propagated the NullReferenceException when trying to call Length on the null Name string.  In procedural code, you'd catch this exception and swallow it because you knew it was benign.  *But you don't get to put an exception handler around the WPF binding code.*  It's called from somewhere deep inside WPF.  So the exception would bubble all the way up to Application.Run, which is not a very useful place to catch it.

So rather than making you centralise your binding exception handlers all the way up in Application.Run, I think the WPF guys decided to swallow the exceptions themselves.  Only a theory though...

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with this. Technically, the `Binding` element only has a string path that's later converted to a `PropertyPath` instance. This, in turn, would be used to navigate up to the target property. Hence, it would probably make sense for this navigator to check for null every step of the way and return it whenever it's met; what remains highly questionable is how it handles *actual* exceptions thrown by property getters getting visited. That, IMHO, is a recipe for catastrophe.

Answer (score 5):

I would argue it is because the cost of producing an Exception is prohibitive. The current implementation works even in the case there are some invalid bindings and in current form that can actually have a very significant effect on performance.  Take this example, create a DataGrid that does binding and this load 1,000 records into it. Measure performance with all bindings correct and again with one of them wrong. The difference is considerable. Add on top of that standing up exception class instances and it could get out of control bad. Just my opinion.

Comment: Interesting thought!  Hadn't considered the perf issue of catching and handling the exception for every item of a list control...

Comment: Bah, I wanted to upvote this but I accidentally "unclicked" the upvote and now I can't re-click it to restore my upvote.  Sorry, Keith -- virtual +1 anyway!

Comment: binding with wrong bindings is slow because of the warning message displayed in the output window in visual studio; output window is very slow

Comment: I thought the same at first but the diff existed in prod code when not attached to a debugger.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know why that is the default behavior, but there are ways around.

For example, even though it will not tell you about the binding error, the Output window will. You can kind of catch that using binding validations as well.

**EDIT:**
I found [this](http://devlicio.us/blogs/christopher_bennage/archive/2009/02/19/testing-bindings-in-wpf.aspx) article that has a very good idea to create test cases that will catch those annoying silent binding errors (and I loved the photo at the top of the article)

Comment: Indeed, you can see the Binding exception in the Output window at runtime. Do you know if you can also know about the exceptions that occurs in design time (ie in Blend) ?

Comment: Link no longer valid

Answer (score 0):

Here is link to a [blog post](http://blog.jordanterrell.com/post/State-Machine-ViewModel.aspx) where the blogger writes about a case where it argues that it does make sense that the binding errors are silent