# WPF OpenFileDialog Suppresses Exception

Tags: c#, wpf, exception, openfiledialog, unhandled-exception

Perhaps I'm using the `OpenFileDialog` incorrectly, but I've found that unhandled exceptions are being suppressed whenever the `OpenFileDialog` is used and the result is passed into my model.

Typically I'll hook ino the `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` event to handle any unhandled exceptions, but any exceptions being raised after using the `OpenFileDialog` are swallowed whole.

The following is an example to reproduce this behavior. If you run the example, you'll see that the exceptions being thrown in the code behind and the `ShellModel.ThrowException` property are correctly caught by the `UnHandledException` handler in the App.xaml.cs. However, the exception being thrown in the `ShellModel.OpenFile` property after using the `OpenFileDialog` is being suppressed.

Why would these exceptions be suppressed?

**App.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;

namespace ExceptionTest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        protected override void OnStartup( StartupEventArgs e )
        {
            base.OnStartup( e );

            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += OnUnhandledException;
        }

        private void OnUnhandledException( object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e )
        {
            var ex = e.ExceptionObject as Exception;

            if( ex == null )
            {
                MessageBox.Show( string.Format( "Null Exception: {0}", e ) );
                return;
            }

            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.AppendLine( "An unhandled exception was encountered. Terminating now." );
            sb.AppendLine();
            sb.AppendLine( "Exception:" );
            sb.AppendLine( ex.Message );

            MessageBox.Show( sb.ToString(), "Whoops...", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error );

            Environment.Exit( 1 );
        }
    }
}
```

**Shell.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="ExceptionTest.Shell"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:Model="clr-namespace:ExceptionTest"
        Title="Exception Test" Height="350" Width="350" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <Model:ShellModel x:Name="Model" />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">

        <Button 
            Click="OnCodeBehind" Margin="20"
            Content="Exception from code behind" Height="25" Width="250" />

        <Button 
           Click="OnThrowExeption"  Margin="20"
            Content="Exception from Model" Height="25" Width="250" />

        <Button 
            Click="OnFindFile" Margin="20"
            Content="Exception from OpenFileDialog" Height="25" Width="250" />

        <Label Content="{Binding OpenFile, Mode=TwoWay}" x:Name="OpenFile"
                     Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto" />

    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**Shell.xaml.cs / Model**

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows;
using Microsoft.Win32;  

namespace ExceptionTest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Shell : Window
    {
        private OpenFileDialog OpenDialog { get; set; }

        public Shell()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            OpenDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            string path = new Uri( Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase ).LocalPath;
            OpenDialog.InitialDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName( path );
            OpenDialog.Multiselect = false;
            OpenDialog.Title = "Find File";
            OpenDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;
        }

        private void OnCodeBehind( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
        {
            throw new Exception( "Exception from Code Behind." );
        }

        private void OnThrowExeption( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
        {
            Model.ThrowException = "Test";
            e.Handled = true;
        }

        private void OnFindFile( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
        {
            OpenDialog.ShowDialog( this );

            string fileName = OpenDialog.FileName;

            if( !string.IsNullOrEmpty( fileName ) )
            {
                OpenDialog.InitialDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName( fileName );
                OpenFile.Content = fileName;
            }
        }
    }

    public class ShellModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _throwException;
        public string ThrowException
        {
            get { return _throwException; }
            set
            {
                _throwException = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged( "ThrowException" );
                throw new Exception( "Exception from Model." );
            }
        }

        private string _openFile;
        public string OpenFile
        {
            get { return _openFile; }
            set
            {
                _openFile = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged( "OpenFile" );
                throw new Exception( "Exception from Model after using OpenFileDialog." );
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged( String info )
        {
            if( PropertyChanged != null )
            {
                PropertyChanged( this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs( info ) );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Resolution

As noted in the answer, this isn't an OpenFileDialog issues, rather its a data binding issue.

Bradley's answer and Hans possible duplicate link pointed to some great information. The links/articles didn't quite provide the resolution I came up with, re: I found there was another exception I could hook into: `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException`

Here's a modified version of my `App.Xaml.cs`:

```
protected override void OnStartup( StartupEventArgs e )
{
    base.OnStartup( e );

    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += OnUnhandledException;

    // The FirstChanceException will catch binding errors
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException += OnFirstChanceException;
}


private void OnFirstChanceException( object sender, FirstChanceExceptionEventArgs e )
{
  // do stuff
}
```

The binding errors are now caught!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why Does WPF Swallow Databinding Exceptions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075289/why-does-wpf-swallow-databinding-exceptions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the OpenFileDialog that's suppressing the exception, but WPF data binding. By default, any exception thrown from C# code that's involved in a property binding will be swallowed by the data binding engine. (You can demonstrate this in your code by replacing the contents of `OnFindFile` with just `OpenFile.Content = "test";`).

To diagnose data binding errors, add a listener to the [`PresentationTraceSources.DataBindingSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa344636%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) trace source. Bea Costa has [a good blog post](http://www.beacosta.com/blog/?p=52) describing how to do this.

Comment: Ahhh! Thanks much. I don't think Bea's blog post provided a runtime solution, but it did point me in the right direction. I'll update my question with the resolution.