# What is the best way to databind a WPF control to a typed dataset?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, strongly-typed-dataset

I have a static, typed dataset that I am using within my WPF application that all the user controls must bind to.

I want compilation to break if the dataset and the UI are out of sync.

What approach have you found best to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's simply not going to happen. Binding exceptions occur at runtime and are not compiler checked for accuracy.

You can get feedback on Binding errors in the debug output, however. See [Why does WPF databinding swallow exceptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978887/why-does-wpf-databinding-swallow-exceptions).