# The null exception is caught in the method” MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.RawValue(Int32 k)” and never thrown again

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2012, entity-framework-5, sql-server-2012

In the below code the SelectedUser is null; I expected to the code below throw an null exception which I can handle somewhere in my code for example:

Application.Current.DispatcherUnhandledException += this.DispatcherUnhandledException;
or
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += this.CurrentDomainUnhandledException;

```
// Code example; here is the SelectedUser null.
this.IsUserInRole = this.SelectedUser.UserRole;
```

Unfortunately, the null exception is caught in the method” MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.RawValue(Int32 k)” and never thrown it again.

I think this is a bug in the .Net library; I cannot find any useful information in the net about the problem. Any help will be appreciated!

**Used Technologies:**

 Windows 7 x64

.Net Framework 4.5

Visual Studio 2012 Update 2

Underlayer:

WPF

Entity Framework

SQL Server 2012

**Call Stack:**

```
Cannot get 'IsUserInRole' value (type 'Boolean') from '' (type 'DataGridViewModel'). BindingExpression:Path=IsUserInRole; DataItem='DataGridViewModel' (HashCode=22143992); target element is 'CheckBox' (Name=''); target property is 'IsChecked' (type 'Nullable`1') TargetInvocationException:'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
...UserInterface.Settings.DataGridViewModel.get_IsUserInRole() in …….\SettingsModule\UserSettingsView\DataGridViewModel.cs:line 521
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetValue(Object obj, Object[] index)
at MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.GetValue(Object item, Int32 level)
at MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.RawValue(Int32 k)'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the exception is swalled by WPF which is done by design.
More on this here:
[Why does WPF databinding swallow exceptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978887/why-does-wpf-databinding-swallow-exceptions)

Comment: Thanks Volker for the this nice solution.